# Spring / Hibernate One to One relationship with extra column

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, one-to-one

Is it possible to have a one to one relationship in Spring / Hibernate with extra-column? If yes how do we do? I think I have to use a join table to link my two entities together and then add an extra column in this join table but I don't know how.

Here is a code sample that modelizes relationship between an employee and a workstation, it uses `@JoinTable` so that the relationship is persisted in a dedicated join table. And I would like to add an extra information in this relationship for example the last time the employee used a given workstation, how would I do that?

Employee entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "emp_workstation", 
      joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
      inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "workstation_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private WorkStation workStation;

    //... getters and setters
}
```

WorkStation entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workstation")
public class WorkStation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "workStation")
    private Employee employee;

    //... getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, may I suggest you to change the relation between Employee and Workstation to create a @ManyToOne .

One-to-one relationships associate **one record** in one table with a single record in the other table.

Many-to-one relationships associate **many record** in one table with a single record in the other table.

Then, use @ManyToOne if :

- There is many workstation in your database and the user get access to
  only one workstation.
- An employee can use different workstation (or the same workstation) but can use only one at a time.

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "workstation_id",
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_workstation_id")
    )
    private WorkStation workStation;
```

According to the question of additional data in a relationship one-to-one should return all datas mapped in your entity.

Then, if you store "the last time the employee used a given workstation", that's mean you may have more then a single record for a given employee in the table "workstation".

Comment: Thanx for your answer